# AWS Lambda request and wait for response in asynchronous way

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a simple problem. I want to create some kind of pipeline. First we have a function that does a request to some external resource (that answer takes a long time - sometimes is more than 60 seconds!). So first function just does a request and go down. And second function handles response of this function.
I currently try to run one lambda which do request, and second which handle response of this request.
I found a repo that has implementation of lambda messaging which is close to my idea https://github.com/pj0616/serverless-async-lambda-api. In this approach we dont wait for the results.
I was trying to run code from here too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html, but it doesnt wait asynchronously for response.

Is it possible to create this flow? Maybe with lambda or step functions?

Below I put a diagram that shows what I'm trying to do.
[image]

Comment: How does the service that you are waiting for send the response back? If you are making an HTTP request and waiting for the response, then you can't do that with 2 Lambda invocations, the one making the request has to sit there and wait on the response to come back on that same HTTP connection.

Comment: anytime you call multiple lambdas, be thinking "step functions"

Comment: have your lambda invoke a step function, take the step function execution id and wait for it to be in a COMPLETE state (this can be error or success). handle that and return the lambda. your step function will hold all your logic

Comment: you don't need step functions in this use case . 
the Lambda_1 can call an external resource (the max duration need to be < 15min)
the lambda_1 invoke the lambda_2  (with InvocationType Event).

this is an example :  https://gist.github.com/ymaghzaz/3382b7a06e83ca93e59105406394c780

Comment: @ymaghzaz I try to run a code that is close to you I implemented a function `call` in the way, that you can find on AWS Lambda documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html (Async handlers), but id doesnt work. The lambda doesnt turn off and just wait for response of http request.

Comment: Guys I updated my post with a diagram.